# Exactly what are these _B_var_Xxxxx and _B_str_Xxxxx members in the VBA COM libraries?

Tags: vba, parsing, com

Imagine the following function call:

```
foo = UCase("bar")
```

I'm parsing this code, and determine that `UCase` is a function call; now I want to resolve that function call to the declaration of the function in the COM library it's defined in.

The idea is to implement a code inspection that determines when a `Variant` built-in function is used when a `String`-returning function exists, like here `UCase$` could be used instead.

It seems the functions I'm after are declared as `_B_var_Ucase` and `_B_str_UCase` in the COM library; I'm picking up a `UCase` member in the `VBA.Strings` module, but it's returning `VT_VOID` - in other words it's a *procedure*, not a *function*.

I could hard-code some logic specific to that group of functions, so that when my resolver code encounters `UCase` I can concatenate `_B_var_` (and for `UCase$`, I can concatenate `_B_str_`) to the identifier I'm trying to resolve, and if I'm lucky I'll get my resolver code to correctly assign the reference to the correct built-in function declaration.

But it's pure guesswork.

I *know* `_var_` stands for `Variant` and `_str_` stands for `String`, but the part I'm missing is exactly how to relate these hidden functions to, say, that `UCase` function call in the VBA code I'm parsing.

Is `UCase("bar")` a call to the `VBA.Strings.UCase` *procedure*? Then how does it work as a *function*? And if not, then how does VBA know to interpret the `UCase` token as a call to `_B_var_UCase`? Is there a consistent naming scheme I can rely on, or is there a relationship between `UCase` and `_B_var_UCase` that I'm not seeing? And what's the `B` for anyway?

The web is outrageously silent about the innards of the VBA standard library, I hope *someone* here might know something about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the **[TYPEATTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221003%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** structure, and in particular, the **typekind** and **tdescAlias** members.

```
typedef struct tagTYPEATTR {
  GUID     guid;
  LCID     lcid;
  DWORD    dwReserved;
  MEMBERID memidConstructor;
  MEMBERID memidDestructor;
  LPOLESTR lpstrSchema;
  ULONG    cbSizeInstance;
  TYPEKIND typekind;
  WORD     cFuncs;
  WORD     cVars;
  WORD     cImplTypes;
  WORD     cbSizeVft;
  WORD     cbAlignment;
  WORD     wTypeFlags;
  WORD     wMajorVerNum;
  WORD     wMinorVerNum;
  TYPEDESC tdescAlias;
  IDLDESC  idldescType;
} TYPEATTR, *LPTYPEATTR;
```

> **tdescAlias**
>
> If typekind is TKIND_ALIAS, specifies the type for which this type is an alias.

So, `UCase(String)` is an *Alias* for `_B_var_Ucase(String)` (where the parameter and the return value are both implicitly Variant.

And, `UCase$(String As String) As String` is an *Alias* for `_B_str_UCase(String As String) As String`

You can call these underlying functions directly from VB/VBA, but you must use square brackets because `_B_str_UCase` and `_B_var_UCase` aren't valid identifiers in VB/VBA.

```
Dim s As String
Dim v As Variant

s = [_B_str_UCase]("abc")
v = [_B_var_UCase](Null)

's = "ABC"
'v = Null
```

The outrageous silence of the web is tempered by the Wayback Machine's [cache](https://web.archive.org/web/20120720070940/http://spec.winprog.org/typeinf2/) of an informative and amusing series of articles by Sean Baxter, but also preserved with formatting, [here](http://www.brakmic.com/iunknown/com-automation-part-2/).

> The TKIND_ALIAS type kind indicates description of a typedef.  The name of the typedef is the name of the type (acquired through GetDocumentation), and the alias type is TYPEATTR::tdescAlias.

As for the `B` in `_B_str_UCase` and `_B_var_UCase` it's hard to say exactly, but it's worth remembering that, in COM, a string is actually a **[BSTR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221069%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

> A **BSTR** (Basic string or binary string) is a string data type that is used by COM, Automation, and Interop functions

This MSDN [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/) goes further and states:

> COM code uses the BSTR to store a Unicode string, short for “Basic String”. (So called because this method of storing strings was developed for OLE Automation, which was at the time motivated by the development of the Visual Basic language engine.)

and then goes on to say:

> If you write a function which takes an argument of type BSTR then you are required to accept NULL as a valid BSTR and treat it the same as a pointer to a zero-length BSTR.  COM uses this convention, as do both Visual Basic and VBScript, so if you want to play well with others you have to obey this convention.  If a string variable in VB happens to be an empty string then VB might pass it as NULL or as a zero-length buffer — it is entirely dependent on the internal workings of the VB program.

So *maybe* the `B` is to remind the authors of those functions that the return type *should* be a BSTR, or maybe the B just means *base* function. I doubt it is important to anyone other than the original developers.

**EDIT**

OleView gives these details:

```
module Strings{ 
    [entry(527), helpcontext(0x000f6eab)]
    BSTR _stdcall _B_str_UCase([in] BSTR String);

    [entry(528), helpcontext(0x000f659b)]
    VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_UCase([in] VARIANT* String);
}

interface _HiddenInterface {
    [restricted, helpcontext(0x000f659b)]
    void _stdcall UCase();
}
```

And the entries (527 and 528) can be found in the DLL exports:

```
ordinal hint RVA      name
    ...
    527   C8 0005E8A0 rtcUpperCaseBstr
    528   C9 00070418 rtcUpperCaseVar
    ....
```