# What is the difference between VBA.Str and VBA.Str$?

Tags: vba

What is the difference between these two code lines

```
Debug.Print VBA.Str(123)
```

and

```
Debug.Print VBA.Str$(123)
```

Answer (score 2):

`Str$` and `Str` are identical except for at least 2 important differences:

1. If the usage of `Str$` returns anything other than a String, you'll get an error:

   ```
   Debug.Print Str(Null)   'Prints Null
   Debug.Print Str$(Null)  'Throws Runtime Error 94 - Invalid use of Null
   ```
2. `Str$` returns a String, whereas `Str` returns a Variant. In general, you should always prefer the strongly typed `Str$` over `Str`

There are many other functions that use `$`-suffixes, like `Left$`, `Mid$` and `Space$`.

If we look at `Left$` (which is really just an alias for `_stdcall _B_str_Left`) and `Left` (which is really just an alias for `_stdcall _B_var_Left`), in the Type Library MIDL, we see that the **input types matter too**.

```
[entry(616), helpcontext(0x000f6ea1)]
BSTR _stdcall _B_str_Left(
                [in] BSTR String, 
                [in] long Length);
[entry(617), helpcontext(0x000f653e)]
VARIANT _stdcall _B_var_Left(
                [in] VARIANT* String, 
                [in] long Length);
```

You can actually use the underlying functions in code:

```
Debug.Print VBA.Strings.[_B_var_Left]("abc",1) 'Prints a
Debug.Print VBA.Strings.[_B_str_Left]("abc",1) 'Prints a
```

And to make matters more confusing, a function like `Join` (that *does* return a String, but which *doesn't* have a corresponding `Join$` function, *can* actually be used *with* a `$` suffix:

```
Debug.Print Join$(Array(1, 2, 3), ".") 'Prints 1.2.3
```

For further discussion, see my answer at [Exactly what are these _B_var_Xxxxx and _B_str_Xxxxx members in the VBA COM libraries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002870/exactly-what-are-these-b-var-xxxxx-and-b-str-xxxxx-members-in-the-vba-com-libr)

Comment: If we hide both the scroll bars in excel while executing macro on more sheets in the workbook improves performance?

Answer (score 0):

Str$ is identical to Str except for the declared type of its return value. i.e.  Str returns a Variant, the Str$ returns a String.

Refer the [msdn link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee200152.aspx)

Comment: Thanks and please suggest which method is better to use?

Comment: I generally prefer STR$(). It depends on the data you are trying to convert to string. Refer https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/aa263420%28v=vs.60%29.aspx for the size of variant and string.

Comment: I admire your way of presentation. It is really useful.

Comment: If we hide both the scroll bars in excel while executing macro on more sheets in the workbook improves performance?